# Expand/Contract a numpy matrix with None

Tags: python, numpy

How can I expand or contract a numpy matrix and populate it with None?

My expected behaviour is:

```py
Y = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)

# Transform it to (7, 3)
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [8, 9, 10],
       [12, 13, 14],
       [None, None, None],
       [None, None, None],
       [None, None, None]], dtype=object)

# Transform it to (2, 3)
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [4, 5, 6]], dtype=object)
```

Basically, retain the submatrix and if the dimensions are larger populate them with None.

Is there a vectorized way to do this?

Comment: first case: slice + concatenate; second case: slice should work right?

Comment: I was looking for more of a way where I just take in input as some dimensions and return the final array without having to worry to much about finding the difference of dimensions to concatenate and all. I mean the latter is what I am doing right now but I felt there should be a btter way

Comment: Vectorization is not very useful with objects. In fact using objects instead of integers is much slower generally because it prevents the use of SIMD operations and cause slow CPython calls instead of native C ones. Even worse: each object needs to be allocated separately and reference counted which is very expensive. It also prevent any future parallelization due to the GIL. Not to mention objects take far more memory space. Please consider using masks instead.

Comment: So you want something that will do the thinking for you?